# How to dynamically create a new array based on a specific value with a loop PHP

Tags: php, arrays

So for example I have an array like this:

```
$a1=array("U001","U002");
/*
Output:
Array ( 
    [0] => U001 
    [1] => U002 
    )
*/
```

And I want to create a new array whose number of elements is based on a value, for example if the value is 2, then the array becomes:

```
$values: 2
$a1=array("U001","U002");
$newArr=array("U001","U001","U002","U002");
/*
Output:
Array ( 
    [0] => U001 
    [1] => U001 
    [2] => U002 
    [3] => U002 
    )
*/
```

Also, if the array itself consists of 3, and the value is 3, then:

```
$values: 3
$a1=array("U001","U002","U003");
$newArr=array("U001","U001","U001","U002","U002","U002","U003","U003","U003");
/*
Output:
Array ( 
    [0] => U001 
    [1] => U001 
    [2] => U001 
    [3] => U002 
    [4] => U002 
    [5] => U002 
    [6] => U003 
    [7] => U003 
    [8] => U003 
    )
*/
```

How can I create a dynamic function to create this new array?
I'm thinking of adding an if-else, but I don't know how to use this in a loop process..

Thanks for any help

Comment: where are your codes?, just start with a foreach on the initial array, then a for loop inside, for each item inside the array, loop it based on how many is there inside. there's nothing but upside in trying it out

Comment: Please provide the code you have written so far.

Comment: @Kevin Yes I've tried your advice, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$a1=["U001","U002"];
$values = 5;
$newArray = [];
foreach($a1 as $item) {
  for ($i= 0; $i < $values; $i++) {
    $newArray[] = $item;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are merging multiple array. You can use `array_merge`.

```
$a = ["a", "b"];
$b = ["c", "d"];

$c = array_merge($a, $b);

print_r($c);

//Output:
/*
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

So like [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3859027/kevin) suggests in the comment, the code is just like this

```
$a1=array("U001","U002");

    foreach($a1 as $x) {
        for ($i=0; $i < count($a1); $i++) { 
            echo $x. "</BR>";
        }
```